# How to change Navbar title and buttons when changing the views via TabBarIOS?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a simple tab based react native navigation app, similar to the Tabbar demo in UIExplorer. But, I want the title of the navbar and the left and right navbar buttons to change when I select a different tab. An example of this navbar behavior is the 'Clock' app on iPhone.

The UIExplorer's Tabbar demo just replaces the view inside the page. I tried embedding a 'NavigatorIOS' as the child component of the Tabbar item, but it gives an error: 'Invariant Violation: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child.'. As a work-around, having an ability to manually modify the navbar title and buttons might work, but I was not successful at that either.

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```js
var TabBarItemIOS = TabBarIOS.Item;
var homeView = require('./App/Views/Home');
var historyView = require('./App/Views/History');

var myapp = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            selectedTab: 'homeTab',
        };
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
            <TabBarIOS
                selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
                <TabBarItemIOS
                    accessibilityLabel="Home"
                    title="Home"
                    name="homeTab"
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'homeTab'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedTab: 'homeTab'
                        });
                    }}>
                <NavigatorIOS
                    tintColor='#FF6600'
                    initialRoute={{
                        title: 'Home',
                        component: homeView,
                    }}/>
                </TabBarItemIOS>

                <TabBarItemIOS
                    accessibilityLabel="History"
                    title="History"
                    name="historyTab"
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'historyTab'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedTab: 'historyTab',
                        });
                    }}>
                    <NavigatorIOS
                        tintColor='#FF6600'
                        initialRoute={{
                            title: 'History'
                            component: historyView,
                        }}/>
                </TabBarItemIOS>
            </TabBarIOS>
        );
    }
});
```

This will render Tabs "Home" & "History" while updating the Navbar title.